# Magento1 Product Attribute PDP Page Slow

Tags: magento-1.9, product

```
$conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($currentProduct);
    $childProducts = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('size')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('color')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('millship')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('closeout')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('msrp')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('soldby_caseqty')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('case_qty')
    ->addAttributeToSort('size_value')
    ->addAttributeToSort('color_value')
    ->joinField(
        'qty',
        'cataloginventory/stock_item',
        'qty',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
        'left'
    );
```

This is My Query its make my pdp page slow

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up using collection cache for this collection f.e. or reduce additional selected attributes.

Comment: how we can use it